# Does Duracell, Inc. manufacture laptop batteries?

Tags: laptop

At any point in time, has Duracell, Inc. ever manufactured batteries for laptops?

Neither Duracell Inc's official site at duracell.com nor the Wikipedia page for Duracell state anything about ever manufacturing laptop batteries. I can find no mention of it anywhere. Various third-party sites have Duracell branded-batteries, but no model numbers are specified and it is not clear if they are counterfeit.

Comment: It is entirely possible that they manufacture batteries for laptops for OEMs, but not for retail sale.

Comment: @RohitGupta Anything is possible, but I reason they would have told me that when I asked candidly if they manufacture *any* laptop batteries themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Duracell support in 2019 after not getting any helpful answers or comments here on SuperUser:

> We’ve expanded our product portfolio in the lap top batteries category by working with our partners, Battery Biz and Batteries Plus.

To answer my own question, the answer is ***no***, Duracell does not manufacture laptop batteries. Instead, Duracell licenses their name to 3rd party battery companies (such as Battery Biz and Batteries Plus).

This explains why a bunch of sites that are *not* duracell.com (and look like they could be counterfeiters) are selling the batteries - they are white-label battery companies merely licensing the name.

Answer (score 1):

I typed “Duracell laptop battery” into Google, and got images, sites, articles, etc. For example, see 
[DuracellDirect.com](https://www.duracelldirect.com/):

[image: homepage listing laptop and camcorder battery categories]

Comment: I erroneously posted and deleted my previous comment, "Yes, I searched for it" (paraphrasing) in trying to edit and add the below:

You are not misunderstanding the question, but that website that is using Duracell's branding, possibly misleading, and is not Duracell Inc.'s actual website. duraceldirect.com is actually a UK company named PSA Parts Ltd. that claims to supply Duracell branded products.

Neither Duracell Inc's official site at duracell.com nor the Wikipedia page for Duracell state anything about ever manufacturing laptop batteries. I can find no mention of it anywhere.

Comment: @aoeu Try a search for model DR5038H: https://www.cnet.com/products/duracell-dr5038h-notebook-battery-li-ion-6600-mah/

Comment: I'm stumbling upon this answer again after many years, and your opening line of "Did you try  searching for it?" comes off at best not having good faith and, at worst, asinine. In my question I detailed places I've looked - did you *really* think I didn't try a basic search? Please be less condescending to people in 2024.